# Count overlapping features using Geopandas

Tags: python, count, union, geopandas, overlapping

Note: I've asked the same question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387773/count-overlapping-features-using-geopandas), but didn't get any feedback so far.

Is there a way to easily count overlapping polygons using Geopandas, the same way as the [ArcGIS Pro Count Overlapping Features](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/count-overlapping-features.htm) works?

[image]

So far my approach was to do union overlay and then [dissolve](https://geopandas.org/aggregation_with_dissolve.html) with `aggfunc='count'` but for some reason the results I get are not correct.

I have 3 overlapping polygons in a single geodataframe:

[image]

[image]

Then I do the overlay:

```
union = gpd.overlay(gdf, gdf, how='union')
```

As a result I get only 9 polygons, although I should get 10 (this is what `union` in QGIS or ArcGIS would return):

[image]

Is there anything wrong with my approach? What is the best way to count overlapping polygons in a single geodataframe?

Full code is below. It returns 9 polygons. Based on my understanding on `union/intersect` operations, it should result in 10 polygons. The intersection of 3 polygons is counted only twice, not three times... The union operation in QGIS for the same set of polygons results in 10 polygons.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely import wkt
data = {'name':  ['polygon A', 'polygon B', 'polygon C'],
        'id': [1, 2, 3],
         'geom': ['MULTIPOLYGON (((36.00000 11.00000, 36.00000 12.00000, 37.00000 12.00000, 37.00000 11.00000, 36.00000 11.00000)))', 'MULTIPOLYGON (((36.50000 11.50000, 37.50000 11.50000, 37.50000 11.00000, 36.50000 11.00000, 36.50000 11.50000)))', 'MULTIPOLYGON (((36.61799 10.80580, 36.61570 11.19321, 36.86327 11.29637, 37.34925 10.91813, 37.00540 10.71182, 36.61799 10.80580)))']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['name','id','geom'])
df['geom'] = df['geom'].apply(wkt.loads)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='geom')

gdf.plot(alpha=0.5, column='id')
union = gpd.overlay(gdf, gdf, how='union')
len(union)
```

Expected result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should work if you want the counts and output of the ArcGIS Pro Count Overlapping Features tool. If you want to include the original polygon, you can comment out/ remove this line: other_poly_list.remove(idx).

```
intersection_polygons_list = []

for idx, row in gdf.iterrows():

    main_poly_gdf = gdf.iloc[idx:idx+1, :]

    print('\n' + 'main poly:', main_poly_gdf['id'].tolist()[:])

    other_poly_list = gdf.index.tolist()

    other_poly_list.remove(idx)

    other_poly_gdf = gdf[gdf.index.isin(other_poly_list)]

    print('other polys:', other_poly_gdf['id'].values.tolist()[:])

    intersection_polygons = gpd.overlay(main_poly_gdf, other_poly_gdf, how='intersection')

    intersection_polygons_list.append(intersection_polygons)


intersections_gdf = pd.concat(intersection_polygons_list)
```

[image]

```
intersections_gdf_gb = intersections_gdf.groupby('name_1').agg({'name_2':'size'})
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. However, as far as I can see this approach gives exactly the same results as my previous approach, i.e. `union = gpd.overlay(gdf, gdf, how='union')`. Note that the number of overlaps for polygon C should be 3, not 2 (all three polygons overlap there). I would like to include original polygons and count them as 1 overlap, the same way Count Overlapping Features tool.